# Databricks PAT token and secret creation

Tags: azure, github-actions, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

We are trying to create a databricks workspace using terraform in Azure. As configured in the terraform script Databricks is created and but continuously getting error on token creation and secret creation. we are using SP to authenticate to Azure.

```
resource "databricks_token" "pat" {  
   comment    = "Using Tf"
   lifetime_seconds = var.token_lifetime
   depends_on = [
     azurerm_databricks_workspace.databricks
  ]
}
```

Error: cannot create token: default auth: cannot configure default credentials. Config: azure_client_secret=***, azure_client_id=**, azure_tenant_id=**. Env: ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID

Creating Using Git workflow and the configured SP is having contributor access to subscription

Tried using automation

Comment: How the Databricks provider is declared?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare Databricks provider correctly - I don't see the `host` parameter in your list. Something like this:

```
provider "databricks" {
  host = "https://${azurerm_databricks_workspace.databricks.workspace_url}"
}
```

Comment: This is fixed by providing databricks provider correctly, Thanks Alex